# Clear a text box value in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I need to clear a text box value when clicked over it in silverlight 5.0.

Pls, help me to solve this issue.

```
    <TextBox Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,53,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="Sample" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" MouseLeftButtonDown="textBox1_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

private void textBox1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

Add to your code (on the constructor or on the UserControl loaded event, for example):

```
textBox1.AddHandler(TextBox.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(textBox1_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
```